# restart/reset and replay a transition css?

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I need to replay a css transition using javascript.
When I reset css style of my div and apply the new transition, nothing happens...

I think both code are executed in the same execution frame and by optimisation, it doesn't change anything...

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/f0s8a8jp/2/

```
test.css({transition: 'none', height: '0px'});
test.css({transition: 'height 1s linear', height: '100px'});
```

The only solution I found for the moment (not realy clean for me), is to use setTimeout beetween the properties reset and the application of new transition : https://jsfiddle.net/f0s8a8jp/3/

Better idea is welcome?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transition will apply on the computed dimension of the element. Setting the CSS property does not compute it. So, setting forth and back the property is like letting it unchanged. It's computed when the browser need to reflow the element.

`setTimeout` will eventually let the time to the browser to compute a reflow in the meanwhile. You could use `requestAnimationFrame` to achieve the same without flickering.

Another hack consists in forcing the browser to reflow right after altering the CSS properties, using `test[0].offsetWidth;` for instance.
The transition is then performed correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/f0s8a8jp/9/

A more in-depth discussion about reflow (and repaint) can be found here: http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/f0s8a8jp/4/

I made it work on `click`, so you need to click on it to see the result.

The only thing I really changed was the order of the code.

Comment: my problem is not the "first setTimeout", it's the second^^ In my usecase, the replay of transition is trigged by anoter method, not by setTimeout ;)

Comment: Well, you'd need to tell my by what it is triggered then.

Comment: it's an action of user, like your click, but it's not realy important here^^ The problem is, how reset and rechange same properties CSS in 1 frame

Comment: So you mean without the `setTimeout`? Just remove it then. Works like a charm without it. https://jsfiddle.net/f0s8a8jp/6/
And if you tell me what function needs to trigger it, I can help you with the code more precisely.

Comment: not for me... i'm using FF. dont work on chromium too... may be are you on mobil phone. If CPU is too slow, it may be works, but it's not a solution ;)

Comment: I tested it on firefox and chrome as well. It works on both like it is supposed to.