# Should I use/avoid jQuery animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, css-transitions

A question popped to mind answering to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439605/restart-reset-and-replay-a-transition-css/37440418?noredirect=1#comment62385004_37440418), where OP wanted to apply this transition:

```
test.css({transition: 'height 1s linear', height: '100px'});
```

And then to go back to this:

```
test.css({transition: 'none', height: '0px'});
```

He said he needed it to be done from js, and asked for a better idea, so I offered this approach:

```
test.animate({height: '100px'}, 1000, 'linear', function(){
    test.css({transition: 'none', height: '0px'});
});
```

Here is my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mqaunyvp/1/

@Matrix commented that JS and jQuery animations are less optimised than native CSS, which is right, but I think not on topic in that context.

So here is the question:

Is it right to accomplish this the way I suggested? Or would you advise against it? Why?

Comment: The animation implementation in jQuery is not very efficient, but [velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) has a similar API and is much better.

Comment: I can agree with @Pointy, `velocity` is very good and efficient. But if you keep your animations simple and not too much, `jQuery` will do the job very good too.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. I rarely move things around on the screen, but sometimes you have to. 
So, it's not a bad habit to have (as far as they are a few, and simple) js animations instead of trying to do it all from native CSS?

Comment: Also thanks @linusg, and any comments on the follow-up will be appreciated.

Comment: And things like moving objects is more easier with JS. I just recommend using CSS for things like text/link animation, hover actions or menu expanding.

Comment: Thanks again @linusg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conclusion from all the comments:

***`jQuery` was not created for animating objects***, so it may be slow and laggy (depending on what and how much you're animating). But scrolling a page with `jQuery`'s `.animate()` function for example works very good in most cases.

***For more advanced animations*** (like moving objects or doing complex or many animations at the same time), use libraries as [`velocity`](http://julian.com/research/velocity/).

***If you just want to animate text style/color or a slide-down menu***, it's faster (and easier IMO) to use CSS transitions/animations.

So it depends on what you're doing. Hope this helps!